# Reactive FormGroup hidden default values

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

Can I initialise a FormGroup with values, and not have the values reflect in the model so the input fields appear blank at start?

I have a `formGroup` as follows:

```
this.fg = this.fb.group({
  saleValue: 0,
  letValue: 0
});
```

Which is bound to my model like so:

```
<form [formGroup]="fg">
  <input formControlName="saleValue" />
  <input formControlName="letValue" />
</form>
```

If a user does not enter a sale/let value, it should be submitted to the server as `0` - hence the initialisation with the formGroup.

However, I do not want this 0 to display in the input field. So when I submit the form using `getValue()`, my values are set as required. Is there a way to achieve this?

I fear I will need to do it manually and initialise the FormGroup controls to `null`, and check both controls for values and `setValue(0)` if they are still `null`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do something like that

```
this.fg = this.fb.group({
  saleValue: '',
  letValue: ''
});
```

in the form markup

```
<form [formGroup]="fg" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitFunction(fg)" >
  <input formControlName="saleValue" />
  <input formControlName="letValue" />
</form>
```

and in submit Function ..

```
onSubmitFunction (form) {
  if (!form.value.saleValue) form.value.saleValue = 0
  if (!form.value.letValue) form.value.letValue= 0

// and then submit the form 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rely on falsy values.

```js
this.fg = this.fb.group({
  saleValue: 0,
  letValue: 0
});

submit() {
  ...
  const value = this.fg.value;
  this.setDefaultValues(value);
  ...
}

setDefaultValues(formValue) {
  formValue.saleValue = formValue.saleValue || 0;
  formValue.letValue = formValue.letValue || 0;
}
```

With this solution, if the input is false (`undefined`, `null` or `''`), the value will be replaced by zero.